# Ошибка: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

Tags: jquery

Пробую простую логин форму, имеется Loading indicator, который зависает. Помогите разобраться.

```
// Attach AJAX "loading" event listener
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart : function() {
        $("#loadingBox").show()
    },
    ajaxStop : function() {
        $("#loadingBox").hide()
    }
});

function loginUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let userData = {
        username : $('#formLogin input[name=username]').val(),
        password : $('#formLogin input[name=passwd]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url : "/login",
        data : userData,
        success : loginSuccess,
        error : handleAjaxError
    });

    function loginSuccess(userData) {
        saveAuthInSession(userData);
        showHideMenuLinks();
        showHomeView();
        showInfo(loginSuccess);
    }

}
```

Если убрать showInfo(loginSuccess), то Loading индицатор исчезает когда заявка прошла успешно, но соответсвенно у меня нет таким образом сообщения об успешной аутентификации.

```
function showInfo(message) {
    $('#infoBox').text(message);
    $('#infoBox').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#infoBox').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в этом коде

```
showInfo(loginSuccess)
```

`loginSuccess` - это **функция**!

При передаче ее в `$('#infoBox').text(message);`

Выполняется [.text(function)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function), в которой опять вызывается `loginSuccess` и так по кругу.

Скорее всего, вместо `loginSuccess` нужно передавать какое-нибудь поле из `userData`, либо просто текст сообщения `"login Success"`

```
function loginSuccess(userData) {
    saveAuthInSession(userData);
    showHideMenuLinks();
    showHomeView();
    showInfo("Login success");
}
```